# Mongodb aggregate $gt returns non matching records

Tags: mongodb, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I would like to count the sum of a field in my database.
I have this pipeline in mongodb:

```
{
    match: {
        'user1': user.id,
        'unreadMessagesCount': { $exists: true, $gt: 0 },
   }
},
{
    group: {
         objectId: null,
         total: { $sum: "$unreadMessagesCount" },
         count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}
```

The results returned is

```
{total: 3, count: 30}
```

The total is correct because I only have 3 records with 1 unreadMessagesCount each. But the count returned is 30 which is wrong. There should only be 3 records matched. When i remove group from pipeline, I get 30 records.

Comment: that should not be the case, test it here :: https://mongoplayground.net/p/j6-4Q2yJhTP

Comment: It should work, please provide sample documents (one each with and without `unreadMessagesCount`)